# Using ASP.NET 4 cookie in Web API edit: Core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I'm adding an Angular app and Web API (edit: Core 2.0) to a legacy ASP.NET 4 application. The legacy application uses Forms Authentication and I can't change that. I'd like the Web API to detect that a user is logged in and set up Claims etc. (or alternative) to authorise subsequent Web API requests.

I've attempted to read the authentication cookie in the Web API but am unable to decrypt it, I believe because ASP.NET Core 2.0 doesn't understand the ASP.NET 4 cookie encryption. I've played around with web config settings for the machine key etc. without success. What are my options here?

Answer (score 0):

Configure your ASP.NET website:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            CookieName = ".AspNetCore.ApplicationCookie",
            TicketDataFormat = new AspNetTicketDataFormat(
       new DataProtectorShim(
           DataProtectionProvider.Create(new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\shared-auth-ticket-keys\"))
           .CreateProtector("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware", "Cookies", "v2"))),
            CookieManager = new ChunkingCookieManager(),
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
   });
```

Then your Core 2 application, they should use the same folder to shared authentication tickets and the same authentication method:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
     services.AddCookieAuthentication(options => { 
        options.AuthenticationScheme = "Cookie",
        options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
        options.CookieName = ".AspNet.SharedCookie";
        options.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
        options.AutomaticChallenge = true;
        options.TicketDataFormat = ew AspNetTicketDataFormat(
       new DataProtectorShim(
           DataProtectionProvider.Create(new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\shared-auth-ticket-keys\"))
           .CreateProtector("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware",
           "Cookies", "v2")))
     });
 }

 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
 {
     app.UseAuthentication();
 }
```

The docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?tabs=aspnetcore2x

Comment: As noted in the link, this is for Core 1 and ASP.NET 4.5 and is incompatible with the stack in question.

Comment: Thanks Isma. Are you saying that this will allow Core 2 to understand cookies created in ASP.NET 4? Have you had that working?

Comment: Hey, I had forgotten the ticket data format, I edited the answer again. I haven't tested this myself but it should work or at least get you in the right direction ;)

Comment: Thanks Isma but I can't change the existing authentication.

Comment: Then just try the asp.net core part but if you can't share the authentication tickets I reckon it's not possible to do this...